# Put limit indices in a group equation

Tags: equations

I want achieve the following equantions group. Exactly like this
[image]

but, when I write LaTeX to get this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage{etex}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{latexsym,fancyhdr,graphicx,delarray,epic,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,keyval,ifthen,moreverb,xy}

%%%%%

\begin{document}

$$
\left\{

\begin{array}{ccc}

\lim_{x \to a}f(x) &=& f(a)\\\

\lim_{x \to b}f(x) &=& f(b)\\\


\lim_{x \to c}f(x) &=& f(c)

\end{array}

\right.

$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried also this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage{etex}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{latexsym,fancyhdr,graphicx,delarray,epic,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,keyval,ifthen,moreverb,xy}

%%%%%

\begin{document}

$$

\left\{

\begin{array}{ccc}

\lim_{x \to a}f(x) &=& f(a)\\\

\lim_{x \to b}f(x) &=& f(b)\\\

\lim_{x \to c}f(x) &=& f(c)

\end{array}

\right.

$$

\begin{eqnarray*}

\lim_{x \to a}f(x) &=& f(a)\\\

\lim_{x \to b}f(x) &=& f(b)\\\

\lim_{x \to c}f(x) &=& f(c)

\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If you want to stick to your syntax, you can do `\begin{array}{*3{>{\displaystyle}c}}` (please note that the spacing around the equal signs is too big in your example). Please do not use `eqnarray`. It is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `dcases` (‘display cases’) environment from `mathtools`.

Note `$$ ... $$` syntax shouldn't be used  in a LaTeX document: it is plain TeX syntax, and can yield bad spacings. The `eqnarray` environment shouldn't be used too: the spacing around the alignment point is not good, and the syntax is more complicated than `align`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{latexsym,fancyhdr,graphicx,delarray,epic,amsfonts,amssymb,lmodern,keyval,ifthen,moreverb,xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{dcases}
\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)\\
\lim_{x \to b}f(x) = f(b)\\
\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)
\end{dcases}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. Also thankful for the tip \[ ... \] instead of $$ ... $$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other options:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{dcases}
        \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)\\
        \lim_{x \to b}f(x) = f(b)\\
        \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation*} 

or with alignment at the equal sign: 
\[
\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        \lim_{x \to a}f(x) &= f(a)\\
        \lim_{x \to b}f(x) &= f(b)\\
        \lim_{x \to c}f(x) &= f(c)
    \end{aligned}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

`dcases` is like `cases` but in display style as you wished. `aligned` set the math in display style as well.

Please do not use `$$ $$` within LaTeX. This is deprecated. Above I show you the two possible replacements for this.

Comment: It works perfectly. Also thankful for the tip about \[ ... \] instead of $$ ... $$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\limits`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\RequirePackage{etex}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym,fancyhdr,graphicx,delarray,epic,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,keyval,ifthen,moreverb,xy}

\begin{document}
\[
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) &=& f(a)\\\
    \lim\limits_{x \to b}f(x) &=& f(b)\\\

    \lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x) &=& f(c)
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]